# How to install an ELF 64-bit LSB executable on Debian?

Tags: gcc, debian, elf, lsb

I'm trying to install the mips-linux-gnu-gcc Toolchain on Debian 7 from a guide, which has the instructions to install it from a directory on the machine (which I already sent in) and has the following command to do so:

> export PATH=toolchain/bin/path:$PATH

and the next step is to check it's version:

> mips-linux-gnu-gcc --version

But the only result I have is the "command not found result", I made sure the files are inside the folder and they are, and checking the mips-linux-gnu-gcc file I have the following result:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I have no experience with this kind of files and I haven't found any other way to install it, so I really need help with this :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! the problem was the directory that I was exporting to PATH, since I installed everything on the root folder I had to put /root/ at the start of the url indicated in the instruction guide.